# Autosize hides base UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want a Form to be resized proportionaly to it's content, so I have set `AutoSize` property to `true` in `GrowAndShrink` mode.

I have a base Form that contains a panel in which there is two bttons:

[image: BaseServiceWindow]

And another Form that inherits from it:

[image: Another form that inherits from BaseServiceWindow]

The problem is that panel containing the two buttons in BaseServiceWindow seems not to be taken in account when using the Autosize property. The result is as you can see: I cannot use the buttons from BaseServiceWindow. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The second picture shows that it may inherits another form other than the form shown in the first picture?

Comment: It is just DevExpress skinning the content on runtime. I just tried using plain form and I get the same result. I guess I'll have to resize manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BaseServiceWindow` form, create a second panel that fills the area above the panel with the two buttons.  You will use this new panel to contain a UserControl.

Then, instead of creating forms that inherit from `BaseServiceWindow`, make them UserControls instead. Create an base UserControl class for your UserControls to inherit from and include virtual methods for the common behavior.

Finally, inject the UserControl into `BaseServiceWindow`. You could have the `BaseServiceWindow` constructor accept the BaseUserControl type each of your UserControls inherits.

Comment: I think this approach would be the proper way to do it.